# SIngle word does'nt wrap for a japaneese word in table

Tags: html, css

I have a table where table width can be anything depending upon number of columns.
In a particular column, there will be contact name in any language.

In all other languages, the single word appears for full width.
But in Japanese language, the single word breaks, by auto wrapping it.

I want to know the exact reason behind it.[image]

[Please find my workout here](http://jsfiddle.net/karthipanraj/yq8u2ygj/)

```
<div id="test" style="border:1px solid #ddd; width:200px">
     <h3>    Normal English Language</h3>

    <table class="tbl eng">
        <tr>
            <th>heading1</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
            <th>Heading3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>accoutrements</td>
            <td>accoutrements</td>
            <td>accoutrements</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
     <h3>    Japaneese Language</h3>

    <table class="tbl jpn">
        <tr>
            <th>Heading1</th>
            <th>Heading2</th>
            <th>Heading3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>わかりません</td>
            <td>わかりません</td>
            <td>の着用</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is looking at your code or sample. Please post an image of what you're seeing and what you expect instead.

Comment: i dont see any auto-wrap.

Comment: I have added image. The thing is i want to know Japanese language behaves differently

Comment: I don't know whether this affects your case or not, but the Japanese language has different attitudes towards word wrapping than English.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the japanese characters, it  is just that the text doesn't fit in the cell (it uses the first row to determine the size) , splitting only occurs on words (separated by space).  In japanese this is more complicated since one character can be one word.

http://jsfiddle.net/s6s6fzbp/
use   tags for the header is advised. and use `nowrap` to prevent it from going to a new line.

```
   <tr>
                <th nowrap>わかりません </th>
                <th>わかりません</th>
                <th>の着用</th>
            </tr>
```

Comment: You can as well set it on css with css property : white-space:nowrap

Answer (score 0):

you could do as mentioned and add `nowrap` to the td's or th's individualy or you could use css on all td's and th's so that they will all not wrap like so:

```
td, th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```